# How to make a slider and an LCD Number in JAVA Swing?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

How can we make the following picture in Java Swing? I have used JSlider for a slider, but any idea how to draw an LCD Number displaying the value of the slider?

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=302) you can find a lot of LCD-like free fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `JPanel` and add a `JLabel` to it. You may need to specify the font of the `JLabel`, and override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the `JPanel` to get it to look like you want.

The value of the `JLabel` is the value is the `JSlider`. You may need to force a repaint of the `JLabel` if the `JSlider` is moved (use an `ActionListener` on the `JSlider` for this).